# Modify metadata of file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I would like to create an app that allows me to easily modify the metadata of any given file.

Is there a way to modify the metadata of any given file type?

Are there any NPM packages that facilitate this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [node-ffmetadata](https://github.com/parshap/node-ffmetadata) npm package for reading & writings file properties.

```
var ffmetadata = require("ffmetadata");

// Read song.mp3 metadata
ffmetadata.read("song.mp3", function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.error("Error reading metadata", err);
    else console.log(data);
});

// Set the artist for song.mp3
var data = {
  artist: "Me",
};
ffmetadata.write("song.mp3", data, function(err) {
    if (err) console.error("Error writing metadata", err);
    else console.log("Data written");
});
```

Comment: [thats only for a limited number file types.](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=FFmpeg_Metadata) i want to be able to modify the metadata for ANY file type